# Deploying Selenium Python script to run on scheduler

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium

So my developer is trying to deploy Selenium on an AWS EC2 instance, but he is getting

Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Unable to capture screenshot"}

Anyone know how to get around this?